# typo3 rootline not work, parent is not ACT when on subpage

Tags: css, navigation, show-hide, submenu, typo3-6.1.x

I'm using `typo3 6.1.7` and try to manage a `submenu`. I would like to have the first level with my main menus on the left. If I click on a main menu which has submenus, these should be shown. Then I would like to be able to click on a submenu and the submenu still is open in the navigation.

I can hide submenu first and when main menu active show the submenu (with css `display:none` and `display:inline-block`)

But when I then click the submenu, the main menu isn't active any more and my website does not know that it should show the submenu in navigation.

`ACTIFSUB` does fires when I click on the main menu and not if I'm on the submenu.

How can I do that? I can't believe that I'm the only one with this need. Thanks!

**EDIT**:
It seems that I have a general problem with rootline/parent and child pages. I tried to insert a breadcrumb menu. But all I can see in the rootline is my current page, there is no rootline. 
I think that is the same problem as my parent page has no ACT set, when I'm on a subpage.
Is there a configuration issue here? That has nothing to do with RealUrl hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this:

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.subMenu {
  entryLevel = 0
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul id="subMenu">|</ul>
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }

    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>    
  }

  2 < .1
  2 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the problem is still the same. When I'm on the submenu, the parent does not know that I'm on his submenu.
What is your css to hide/show the submenu with this configuration?

Comment: only the subpages of the active menu points are shown, there is nothing special with CSS, just some "list-style: none;" font-styles etc.

Comment: have a look on my EDIT, Thanks!